# Obter o tamanho do conteudo retornado na requisicao

Tags: java, spring-boot

Olá, estou utilizando um interceptor que irá interceptar antes e depois da requisição. O objetivo disso é obter o tamanho do conteúdo enviado e retornado, porém, não sei de um jeito para obter a resposta, parece que o **response** não tem um método para pega-lo

```
    @Component
public class DataUsageInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler
    ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Tamanho da requisicao: " + request.getContentLength());
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, Exception ex
    ) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Tamanho da resposta: ??");

        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ler o `content-length` do Response Header para conseguir esta informação:

```
response.getHeader("content-length");
```

Esta informação corresponde ao tamanho do response compactado (se for o caso) por meio de Gzip ¹. Então um response com tamanho de 25 KB pode ter, descompactado, mais de 120 KB.

<sup>¹: Você pode conferir se tem gzip habilitado lendo o reponse header `content-encoding`.</sup>

Comment: Bom tarde. Cara o valor veio nulo para ambos (content-length e content-encoding). O que sera que houve ?